# Batch file : copy all file except those its name contain some substring

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd, filenames

first of all im beginner. i want to create batch file to search through specific folder (including all it subfolder) and copy all file inside it except those which filename contain some specific string,this is what i have so far

```
set now=fish        
set logDirectory="C:\Users\paiseha\Desktop\bb\"      
for /r %logDirectory% %%i IN (*%now%*.*) do (          
rem copy process goes here            
)
```

let say i have 3 file in it

```
  C:\Users\fareast\Desktop\bb\one.txt  
  C:\Users\fareast\Desktop\bb\twofishtwo.txt  
  C:\Users\fareast\Desktop\bb\three.txt
```

so i want to copy file one.txt and three.txt only, but instead it copy only the second one,i know its because of *****%now%*.* so how can i invert it so that it does the other way around, help me pls, thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
@ECHO OFF &setlocal
set "now=fish"        
set "logDirectory=C:\Users\paiseha\Desktop\bb"      
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d/b/s "%logDirectory%"^|findstr /riv "^.*[\\][^\\]*%now%[^\\]*$"') do (          
  rem copy process goes here            
)
```

***EDIT:*** *The `\` character is represented as `[\\]` instead of `\\` because of a quirk on how Vista FINDSTR regex escapes `\`. Vista requires `\\\\`, but XP and Win 7 use `\\`. The only representation that works on all platforms is `[\\]`. See [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053) for more info.*

Comment: Consider a path containing `%now%`... Would work with the directory/exclude-string combo specified, but not in the general case :( soz...

Comment: thanks for the reply, the code u give loop thru "C:\Users\fareast\Desktop\" not "C:\Users\paiseha\Desktop\bb\", why is that?

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d/s/b "%logDirectory%" ') do echo %%~nxa|findstr /i /L "%now%" >nul&if errorlevel 1 ECHO COPY "%%a"
```

should work for you.

Comment: why does it loop thru parent directory as well? i meant instead of loop through "C:\Users\paiseha\Desktop\bb\" as i set it loop through directory "C:\Users\paiseha\Desktop\"

Comment: @paiseha : same edit as @Endoro required - quote moved in `set log...` to enclose `var=string` instead of `var="quoted string"`. The first assigns the value without trailing spaces (if present) whereas the second will assign a quoted-value AND any strat trailing spaces on the line to `var`.

Comment: +1, But the FINDSTR search should probably use the `/L` literal option in addition to the `/I` option. Without `/L` the solution will fail if `now` is something like `.abc` because the `.` will match any character.

Comment: Another option is to use `FIND /I` instead of `FINDSTR /IL`. Also it is shorter to use `|| copy "%%a"` instead of `& if errorlevel 1 copy "%%a"`...

Comment: @dbenham Yeah - fair enough on the /L switch - edited-in. As for `||` vs `&&` - I never use them, but only because I can never remember which is which is what...